# Замена POSIX регулярного выражения PCRE аналогом

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, конвертировать функцию `ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $name);` в функцию `preg_replace`. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\.]/i', "", $name)`